# Dynamically Removing Controls from Update Panel.

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have an update panel and I need to remove all the controls that I dynamically added so I can re-add them on AsyncPostBack. Everytime I try to do this I get an error stating "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute". Below is the code that I am using to try an remove the LiteralControls, however; once I figure out the issue I will have to remove other types. Does anyone have any

```
                    foreach(Control xxl in UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.OfType<Control>())
                {
                    Label2.Text = Label2.Text + xxl.GetType();

                    foreach (LiteralControl lc in UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.OfType<LiteralControl>())
                    {
                    LiteralControl myLit = (LiteralControl)lc;
                    UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Remove(myLit);
                    UpdatePanel1.Update();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Don't do foreach, do a for, with an index and count backward

Comment: If you remove items while your Enumerating the loop, you will receive an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify items using a `foreach` loop, dynamic control or not.

If you want to modify items, you have to use a normal `for` loop.

Some general advice is that using dynamic controls is HARD and it is generally advised to avoid it at all costs, and use different `asp:Panel`s to change the content by toggling `Visibility`. Especially with `UpdatePanel`s as they tend to be some of the most finicky controls and what you can place inside them is limited. I do understand that "general" advice may hardly be applicable to your particular project, do the best you can.

Comment: How would I loop through the controls in the update panel in a for loop? Unfortunately this has to use AsyncPostBack which is why I am using the UpdatePanel control :(

Comment: I am assuming something like this.   var myControl = (Control)UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls[i];

Comment: @ChrisLombardi Yes, like that : )