# Dynamically removing control from the panel and updating the panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a following scenario , in which I am dynamically creating bunch of controls in the panel and I have also the feature of removing and adding controls in the panel later on.

Following controls , I want to remove from the panel using the selection of the checkbox that is inside the each of the subcontrol .

[image: Before Removal]

**Removal Code**

Using the Idea mentioned in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412743/dynamically-removing-controls-from-update-panel) , I avoided foreach loop and came up with the following code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < panelDetection.Controls.Count; i++)
{
  if (panelDetection.Controls[i] is ImageControl)
  {
    ImageControl imageControl = (ImageControl)panelDetection.Controls[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < imageControl.Controls.Count; j++)
    {
      if (imageControl.Controls[j] is CheckBox)
      {
        CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)(imageControl.Controls[j]);
        if (chkBox.Checked)
        {
          chkBox.Click -= CheckBox_Click;
          panelDetection.Controls.Remove(imageControl);
          imageControl.Dispose();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the result is very strange as the controls are not getting removed of from the panel in an expected way. You can see that all selected controls are not getting removed from the panel.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this functionality using some other idea?

Comment: This looks like common error of removing things from a list while iterating over the list in a loop. `for(int i=0;i<panelDetection.Controls.Count;i++)` - as you remove things, the indexes of subsequent items change. One solution is to iterate backwards: `for (int i = panelDetection.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: With a small collection, you can also dispose the element at index `0` (no *special performance requirements*) --  You don't need this: `panelDetection.Controls.Remove(imageControl);`, since when you dispose of the ImageControl, one line after, the child Control is automatically removed from Parent's Controls collection -- The ImageControl is supposed to dispose of its child Controls (just a CheckBox here, apparently) when it's disposed

Comment: The image may also need to be disposed of, depending on its origin and how it's presented